# Entitlements.plist file missing when creating project in Visual studio Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.ios, xamarin

When creating a project in `Xamarin Studio` on our Build mac there is a `entitlements.plist` file in the root of the project.

Apparently this file is needed when a customer wants to resign the app we created for them with their own provisioning profile. if im not wrong the file is obsolete in a appstore deploy, however the client wants to test it before releasing it with their `adhoc` profile.

When we create a project in `Visual Studio 2010` it seems to be missing. might this be a bug in the `Visual studio` plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will only get this file if you add it to the iOS project by enabling entitlements.
Go to the project's properties in the solution explorer and in there to "*iOS Application*".
There's a checkbox for the entitlements. Tick it and the plist file will be added to your project.

[image: Visual Studio iOS Settings]

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio 2010 or 2012? The Entitlements section seems to be missing in our project properties :( Also tried updating the plugin but to no avail.

Comment: Found it, was looking in the wrong project properties most likely. thanks a lot for the help